# ReactJS rendering multiple times when page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kOBF.png)

Hi, I'm having a problem with my choice state. I initially applied "popular" to it to call an API with a query of "popular", but when the page loads it is executed 3-4 times.

Can't figure out what's triggering this to happen.

My main goal is to create a category button and when the buttons are clicked it will call an API with a query depending on the button that is clicked then save the data's and output it with simple fade-in animation. but when I click the button, it refreshes and animates the content multiple times.

I attached a screenshot of the initial page load. As you can see it was executed 4 times.

Here's the App.js code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Nav from "./components/Nav/Nav";
import Carousel from "./components/Carousel/Carousel";
import Category from "./components/Menu_Bar/Category/Category";
import Movies from "./components/Movies/Movies";
import Genres from "./components/Menu_Bar/Genres/Genres";

//import css files
import "./App.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";

import Slider from "react-slick";

//helpers - configs
import CONFIG from "./components/configs/Config";

function App() {
  //states
  const [mainState, setMainState] = useState([]); //main state as a backup when filtering
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]); //state from api
  const [choice, setChoice] = useState("popular"); //initially set the category into "popular"
  const [carouselImgs, setCarousel] = useState([]); //state for carousel images - want to use only popular banners
  console.log(choice); //this was executed 4 times
  //search function
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [choice]);

  //fetch images for carousel
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDataCarousel();
    // console.log("useeffect 2");
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    let urlFetch = `${CONFIG.BASE_URL}movie/${choice}?api_key=${CONFIG.API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=`;
    let newUrl = [];
    let movieCollection = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
      newUrl.push(fetch(urlFetch + i).then(res => res.json()));
    }
    const responses = await Promise.all(newUrl);
    responses.forEach(response => {
      response.results.map(res => {
        return movieCollection.push(res);
      });
    });
    setMovies(movieCollection);

    setMainState(movieCollection);
  };

  //carousel images fetch
  const fetchDataCarousel = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `${CONFIG.BASE_URL}movie/popular?api_key=${CONFIG.API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    setCarousel(data.results);
  };
  const getQuery = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setQuery(search);
  };

  //Genre function
  const getOptID = e => {
    const genreID = parseInt(e.target.value);
    if (genreID === 0) {
      setMovies(mainState);
      return;
    }
    const newMovies = mainState.filter(movie => {
      return movie.genre_ids.indexOf(genreID) !== -1;
    });

    setMovies(newMovies);
  };
  //slider settings
  var settings = {
    arrows: false,
    autoplay: true,
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Nav getSearch={setSearch} submit={getQuery} />

      <Slider {...settings}>
        {/* loop through carouselImgs state then output <Carousel /> for each instance */}

        {carouselImgs.map(carouselImg => (
          <Carousel
            key={carouselImg.id}
            img={CONFIG.BASE_IMG_URL + carouselImg.backdrop_path}
            movieTitle={carouselImg.title}
          />
        ))}
      </Slider>

      <div className="menu__bar">
        <div className="container">
          <Category getChoice={setChoice} /> //here is the category buttons

          <Genres getId={getOptID} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="container movies_container">
        <Movies movies={movies} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It is really triggered 4 times? console.log showing 4 entries does not mean that the query is executed 4 times that only means that the component is re-rendered 4 times, wich is totally fine. . Check the network request to verify if it is really fetching 4 times. But as you have it inside a useEffect without any dependencies I highly doubt it.

Comment: Ahh yes. It is re-rendered 4 times. Why is that?

Comment: Everytime you mutate a hook property aka `setX` the DOM rerenders itself.